# Is the father responsible to clothe and room his older children

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, children

Until the age of 6 the father is obligated to feed, clothe and room his children. And it is enforceable. Then until 13/12 he should still do it.
But after 13/12 he is only obligated to do it as tzedoko (S"A E"H [71](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.71?lang=bi))

This [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=55NdTR7HfYAC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=rabbi%20moshe%20feinstein) and this [link](http://dinonline.org/2014/08/30/the-obligation-to-support-ones-child/) seem to claim that according to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein the father's obligation to support his children is until a greater age (and it is not Tzedoko)

But to me it seems Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was only talking about support of food (this is an obligation to his wife to give her food to support [guests](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.64b.15)), but that the father is not obligated to clothe and room his children after 13/12 (except as tzedoko)

(their source seems to be [I"M Y"D 1 143](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=279) and E"H 1 106 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMk8H.jpg)     [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3YJf.jpg)     [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Smzb.jpg)    [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LR24.jpg)    [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQwrX.jpg) (please excuse the image quality))

Please explain if I am wrong and bring evidence to that

PS can someone explain why the obligation to give wife food to feed guests is not in the Rambam or Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: There may also be a consideration of dina demalchusah dina as well, since there are laws within the various countries as to the obligation of parents.

Comment: @sabbahillel Right, because this is a monetary obligation, and thus subject to Dina DeMalghutah.

Comment: but since many people start working after 18, there seems to be a time which Rav Moshe will obligate to feed but the law will not,  "Parental obligations typically end when a child reaches the age of majority, which is 18 years old in most states. "..."One way parental obligations can be terminated before the age of majority is by emancipation. Emancipation is the legal process that allows a minor to assume responsibility for his or her welfare. When a child becomes emancipated, his or her parents are no longer legally obligated to support the child."

Comment: from http://family.findlaw.com/emancipation-of-minors/how-long-do-parents-legal-obligations-to-their-children-continue.html and   "emancipation can only be achieved automatically, if a minor does one of the following:Gets married ... Joins the Armed Forces... Reaches the age of majority" from http://family.findlaw.com/emancipation-of-minors/automatic-emancipation-of-minors.html

Comment: @AlBerko or are you claiming that if the law does not obligate the halacha also does not? (if so why did Rav Moshe Feinstein not write this, when writing about the custom in America, third line here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=280

Comment: @hazoriz What does the law in America say about it? What can the court obligate a couple toward their children?

Comment: Citing from the link above: "Over the years, various Dayanim of the Rabbinate related to the enactment differently, some seeing it as enforceable and others considering it unenforceable. Some related to it as a rabbinic enactment and others as an extension of the laws of tzedakah (see Rabbinic Judgments, Vol. 11, pp. 215-216)."

Comment: @AlBerko (regarding the law, my above comments are not enough?) regarding your citation, is that not regarding the takono by the chief rabbinat of Israel and has nothing to do with the diaspora?

Comment: Someone please help me find "*Rabbinic Judgments*, Vol. 11, pp. 215-216"

Comment: Is your question specifically about R' Moshe's view? if so, you better mention it in the title. I was thinking about a more general question: **How come the Torah does not obligate a person to be financially responsible for his little kids?**

Comment: @AlBerko if seems Rav Moshe is the strict one , I am interested if someone respectable says that the father is obligated to even more